# Checking if a pandas column value is present in another pandas column (list)

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas column with a string value and I want to see if a separate column (listed format) contains the string at all.

| Category | top predicted |
| --- | --- |
| Category A. Molecular Pathogenesis and Physiology | `list see below` |

```
[("Category A. Molecular Pathogenesis and Physiology::HiClass::Separator::1. Amyloid beta::HiClass::Separator::f. Amyloid Structure",
  0.054),
 ('Category B. Diagnosis and Assessment::HiClass::Separator::8. Methodologies::HiClass::Separator::None',
  0.049),
 ('Category B. Diagnosis and Assessment::HiClass::Separator::1. Fluid Biomarkers::HiClass::Separator::b. Blood-based',
  0.035)]
```

The list generated provides `Category` and 2 further sub-categories.

What I desire is a way to determine and identify how many times the `Category` column value appears in the list for column `top predicted`. In the above case "*Category A. Molecular Pathogenesis and Physiology*" for example would return a 1. If the value was "*Category B. Diagnosis and Assessment*" then 2 would be returned.
This would then iterate through the rows in the pandas dataframe.

Any help in achieving this would be much appreciated :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second column contains a list of tuples, which in turn contain the strings to check for. The following lines of code should do it:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum(1 for x in row['top predicted'] if row['Category'] in x[0]), axis=1)
```

You should use `apply()` instead of iterating over the rows as you suggested.

Comment: Hi @Jan, thanks for your response. I tried the method and it returns the following error: `TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.float64' is not iterable`
This is because of the score in the second column perhaps?

Comment: Hi @dinho, indeed, let me correct my answer.